# Google Login in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I searched in Google for **Google Login setup in Angular 7** and found some interesting results. What is the difference between **angular6-social-login** Node package & **angularx-social-login** Node Package.

Is both are same?

Is it possible to setup Google Login without using the these Node Packages?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Universal Login provided by Auth0 instead of these Node Packages. With Auth0 you can get **authentication as a service** so you can solve this problem easily.

Please have a look at this page:
https://auth0.com/universal-login

Also, you can find a bunch of videos in this link to get started:
https://auth0.com/resources/videos

I hope you can find all you need over there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to set login with the social login packages by using the client id from the google console. Here I have provided the sample code using social login for your reference.

UserAuthentication.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { GoogleLoginProvider, SocialAuthService, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  public socialUser!: SocialUser;
  public username:any;
  isLoggedin: boolean=false;
  subscription:any; 

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService,private service:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });    
    
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.socialUser = user;
      this.username=this.socialUser.name;
      this.isLoggedin = (user != null);
      console.log(this.socialUser);
    });
  }

  loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signOut();
  }
```

App.module.ts:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              '271611125754-vr0512mqoes0jrmhttei64vvrehragcj.apps.googleusercontent.com'//Client id
            )
          }
        ]
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }    
  ],
```